# How to check for no value cells ?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete all rows that contain no value. If a row contains formula or formatting but no value , it is to be deleted

The following works fine only for rows that have no value and formulas

```
Sub test()
 [a:a].SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

However the above does not delete a row if a `A` cell contains a formula . How can I improve it ?

Comment: you want to delete row if _all_ cells in row doesn't contains values, or cell in col A doesn't contain values?

Comment: I'm sure you've tried this already, but looping over all the cells and checking cell.Formula = "" would work.  Bit slow though, although you could exclude rows which intersect with your test above.

Comment: I want to delete a row if only cell in column `A` contains no value

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Sub CleanupCrew()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 
                      'Replace 1 with either the number of your sheet or "itsName"

    last = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = last to 1 Step -1
        If ws.Cells(x, 1) = "" Or ws.Cells(x, 1).Formula <> "" Then
            ws.Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

It will loop through all the rows (starting from the last) and delete all those that have either no value or a formula in column A. Hope this is what you were looking for. If not, let me know, I'll provide some more support!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `HasFormula` on the range object:

```
Range.HasFormula
```

will return true if the range contains a fomula, and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somthing like this:

```
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
[a:a].AutoFilter 1, "="
[a:a].Resize(Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells( _
    xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Where `Sheet1` is the worksheet codename you're working on.
So basically, this filters all `Blanks` and deletes it regardless if it's a `No value` blank or `Formula` blank (e.g. ="")